Grant service account access to a single cluster within a project
Use case
We have a test-only cluster that we want to use as part of a Github Actions pipeline. We want the pipeline to be able to do pretty much whatever it likes within the cluster - create/delete namespaces, resources and so on.
Approach
To this end, we have create a google service account (not to be confused with a kubernetes-level service account or "KSA") and attached the following roles for the GCP project in question:

roles/container.clusterViewer
roles/container.developer

Then, we've used Google's auth action to authenticate as this SA when running the action.
The problem
The outlined approach works, however it results in the SA having access to all clusters within this particular GCloud project. For principal of least privilege, I'd like to restrict it to just the cluster in question.
I thought adding a condition to the roles/container.developer role assignment would be the answer, but I've been unable to get this to work. The docs suggest I should be able to use a resource name for the cluster: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-resource-attributes#resource-name, but attempts at this have failed. I tried resource.name == "projects/<project>/locations/<location>/clusters/<name>", as well as various .endsWith recipes, but nothing worked. Then I tried just:
resource.type == "container.googleapis.com/Clusters"

And I still get a permissions error trying to create a namespace. This suggests to me that the resource type that's passed up when trying to create a namespace is not actually the Cluster - and so I can't specify the type of condition I want.
And so that leaves me stuck. What am I missing? What's the "proper" way to do something like this?

You mentioned you are using resource.type . Have you tried using  resource.name like shown here in official gcp documentation.

Ah oops, that was a typo in my original post - resource.name is what I was trying before I resorted to the generic resource.type line to see if it was even a cluster. Have edited the post, thanks for spotting!

Hey Did you get a chance to check my answer? Has it helped you to solve your issue? What should I do when someone answers my question?

If you want to restrict your service account or any user to only one particular cluster then you can try these following methods :
Using RBAC(Role Based Access Control) you can define which user can perform what actions in a cluster by using Role binding you can restrict the service account only to perform actions in a particular cluster.
The other way is you can use Tags with IAM which can help you to create a key value pair that will identify the resource and apply the conditions you are set for the user.

“A tag is a key-value pair that is attached to a Google Cloud resource. You can conditionally grant IAM roles or conditionally deny IAM permissions based on whether a resource has a specific tag.”

The other workaround is you can try to create a custom roles and set permissions along with conditions since as you mentioned the roles/container.developer is not working as expected with the condition “resource.type == "container.googleapis.com/Clusters".
If you want to create a custom role then don’t forget to give all the access which are equivalent to roles/container.developer to the custom role.
